# Can Open read sensor data

Tags: c, can-bus

I just bought a „Contelec Vert-x“ degree sensor and connected it via can bus on my LPC55S16 Board.

The question now is how do i read the data the sensor gives me with CanOpen. The documentation is not good and the examples for MCUXpresso are just for Master and Slave boards.

Comment: We're happy to have you here with us and you need to provide an example of your problem so we can reproduce it with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Canopen is just a layer on top of CAN Bus. Before Canopen you should read can bus. I haven't work with LPC55S16 Board but I think you can find a simple CAN driver for that board or may be it is already provided? Once you are able to read/write on CAN bus properly, you should learn how Contelec Vert-x communicates. CANOpen shouldn't scare you. It simply gives names to some messagw IDs and defines some certain messaging flows.